# How to get device model from /dev/usb/xxx?

Tags: usb, printing

`lsusb` shows me this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. Dell USB Entry Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b8:0e27 Seiko Epson Corp. TM-T20X
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1753:c902 GERTEC Telecomunicacoes Ltda. PPC930 Pinpad Terminal
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also have a udev .rules files that contains:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usblp", MODE="0660", GROUP="lp", SYMLINK+="printer"`

That works nicely and I have a `/dev/printer`

I want to issue a shell command to get printer info to pass to a program, so it knows which thermal printer it's dealing with (there are some differences in fonts, etc).

How do I query which devide (name or id) is on /dev/printer that would output something like `04b8:0e27` or `TM-T20X`?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: made the question more clear, thanks.

Comment: Does this show detail you want? `/usr/sbin/lpinfo -v`